# keep data.frame from list based on condition?

Tags: r

```
d1 <- data.frame(y1=c(1,2,3), y2=c(4,5,6), y3=c(8,8,8), y4=c(1,1,1))
d2 <- data.frame(y1=c(3,2,1), y2=c(6,5,4), y3=c(4,4,4), y4=c(10,10,10))
d3 <- data.frame(y1=c(6,5,4), y2=c(3,2,1), y3=c(8,8,8), y4=c(1,1,1))
d4 <- data.frame(y1=c(9,9,9), y2=c(8,8,8), y3=c(8,8,8), y4=c(1,1,1))

dat = mget(paste0("d", 1:4))
```

From this list I want to keep the dataframe(s) where (1) y3 is between 1 and (2) 5 and y4 is between 5 and 11.

Values in y3 and y4 are the same in each dataframe.

The final output will be:

```
> dat
   $d2
     y1 y2 
   1  3  6  
   2  2  5  
   3  1  4
```

Comment: Just a minor point that `mget` is a vectorized version of `get` that returns a `list`. You can replace `dat=sapply(paste('d', seq(2,4,1), sep=''), get, environment(), simplify = FALSE)` with the much simpler `dat = mget(paste0("d", 1:4))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Filter` (note the capital `F`) is a base function that can filter a list based on a function. Here we write a custom anonymous function based on your criteria. I wasn't really sure whether your "between" means `>` or `>=`, but you can edit easily as you like.

```
Filter(x = dat, f = \(x) all(x$y3 > 1 & x$y3 < 5 & x$y4 > 5 & x$y4 < 11))
# # $d2
# #   y1 y2 y3 y4
# # 1  3  6  4 10
# # 2  2  5  4 10
# # 3  1  4  4 10
```

Comment: Thank, how to remove y3 and y4 from the output?

Comment: Call the output above `filtered_list`, then `result = lapply(filtered_list, \(x) {x[(c("y3", "y4)] = list(NULL); x})`. Or pipe it together, `result = dat |> Filter(f = \(x) all(x$y3 > 1 & x$y3 < 5 & x$y4 > 5 & x$y4 < 11)) |> lapply(\(x) {x[(c("y3", "y4)] = list(NULL); x}))`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)
map(dat, \(x) x |> filter(between(y3, 1, 5) & between(y4, 5, 11))) |> keep(\(x) nrow(x) > 0)

$d2
  y1 y2 y3 y4
1  3  6  4 10
2  2  5  4 10
3  1  4  4 10
```

Comment: Usually better to explain the code, rather than just posting a one-liner

Answer (score 1):

From the `dat`list of dfs, keep those with all `y3` values within 1:5 and all `y4` within 5:11.

```
purrr::keep(dat, \(x) all(x$y3 %in% 1:5 & x$y4 %in% 5:11))
```

(Edited after @alan and @gregor suggestions)

Comment: Thank, how to remove y3 and y4 from the output?

Comment: `== TRUE` is almost never needed. `all()` already returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`

Comment: Usually better to explain the code, rather than just posting a one-liner

Comment: @temor since the output is a list, you can select what you want from the its elements with `map(output, \(x) x[, 1:2])`. This selects the first and second columns.